# Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_SelectionChange event not engaging

Tags: excel, vba, office365

After some time passed using Sheet27 both events stopped working. The code for the events are on Sheet27. No other Sub is called. There are four events for Sheet27

The file is located on OneDrive and
I'm using Office365 on Windows 10 latest build. I built this app for other users who may have different Excel versions (2010 to Latest) and I'm not sure if this is going to repeat in other versions. Any light shone on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

When it stopped working I had to exit Excel entirely and reopen the file. I tried closing and reopening the file but that didn't work.

I thought it could have been the graphics card because it's a little bit older but when exiting Excel and reopening file worked, it cancelled that notion.

Maybe something along the code is causing it to stop working that I cannot see due to lack of expertise.

Maybe to do with the Excel Application or the Excel Workbook itself and not the Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_SelectionChange event because it works flawlessly when the file newly opened.

Here is Sheet27 Code: I labeled the sections that stopped working

```
Option Explicit
Dim RowNum As Long


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Stopped working after some use

Application.EnableEvents = False
'This section enables and disables rows 4 through 12 via cell D3 Value of 1-10, 10 being max
'Row 3 is always shown

Select Case Range("D3").Value
    Case "": Range("4:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True      'If D3 is intentionally blank
    Case 1: Range("4:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 2
            Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("5:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 3
            Rows("4:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("6:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 4
            Rows("4:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("7:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 5
            Rows("4:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("8:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 6
            Rows("4:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("9:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 7
            Rows("4:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("10:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 8
            Rows("4:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("11:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 9
            Rows("4:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("12:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case 10
            Rows("4:12").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is > 10: MsgBox "Maximum 10 employees. If you need more than 10, add more after posting these 10.", vbInformation, "Maximum 10 Rows"
    End Select
    
Application.EnableEvents = True

'***************************************************************
'Monthly or weekly Employee 
Application.EnableEvents = False

RowNum = Target.Row
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F3:F12")) Is Nothing Then     'Employee Name Field. Dropdown list - 10 Rows - F3:F12

'Get last row in Sheet Posting to
    Range("V3").Value = Worksheets(Range("B1").Value).Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    If Range("M" & RowNum).Value = "12" Then   '12=Monthly or 52=Weekly. M3 has Index/Match formula associated to Employee Name
        Range("G" & RowNum).Value = "1"           'If M3=12 then Monthly paid employee value is 1 (multiplier for monthly wage on posting Month sheet)
    Else
        Range("G" & RowNum & ":L" & RowNum).Value = ""           'clear associated data in G3:L3 if M3=52 (weekly paid employee)
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

'***********************************************************************
'If Loan Balance is 0 or less show warning

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim LoanDue As Variant
Dim EmpName As String

RowNum = Target.Row
EmpName = Range("F" & RowNum).Value
LoanDue = Range("P" & RowNum).Value

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J3:J12")) Is Nothing Then
   If LoanDue < 0 Then
        Target.Value = ""
        Target.Select
        MsgBox EmpName & "'s Loan Balance is Zero." & vbNewLine & _
            "Entered payment was cleared." & vbNewLine & _
            "Please notify Admin on " & EmpName & "'s record to verify or make changes.", _
            vbExclamation, "Loan Payment Error"
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
    
    Private Sub PayDateInfoOnLbl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single) 'This section works all the time
'Show Note
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TxtBxPayDate")).Visible = msoTrue
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub PayDateInfoOffLbl_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single) 'This section works all the time
'Hide Note
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TxtBxPayDate")).Visible = msoFalse
    End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 'Stopped working after some use

Dim VacBal As String
Dim SickBal As String
Dim EmpName As String

RowNum = Target.Row
VacBal = Range("R" & RowNum).Value   'INDEX/MATCH Formula in cell to retrieve data from EmployeeInfo sheet 
SickBal = Range("T" & RowNum).Value  'INDEX/MATCH Formula in cell to retrieve data from EmployeeInfo sheet 
EmpName = Range("F" & RowNum).Value 

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K3:K12")) Is Nothing Then
    If VacBal = "" Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox EmpName & " has " & VacBal & " Vacation Day(s) remaining.", vbInformation, "Vacation Days Balance"
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L3:L12")) Is Nothing Then
    If SickBal = "" Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox EmpName & " has " & SickBal & " Sick Day(s) remaining.", vbInformation, "Sick Days Balance"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: One of your events has probably thrown an error between `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` leaving events disabled. To verify type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the immediate window and see if your events then work.  To fix, include an error handler to ensure events are turned back on

Comment: @chrisneilsen, It didn't work. I left out an error handler (for now) to find as many errors as possible. I'm trying to do everything wrong on the sheet to find errors or to make it easier, before the end user finds them.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, the result of your suggestion gave me, 'Application.EnableEvents = True',  a FALSE which means it's stuck in the FALSE mode and won't come out. I'm going to try moving the 'Application.EnableEvents = True' up the code for each section where it's truly needed. Then I'll try moving the 'Application.EnableEvents = False' down further only where it's truly needed.

Comment: SOLVED! An external macro (Sub()) to transfer the data from Sheet27 to another sheet was cancelling the `Application.EnableEvents = True` in Sheet27 Worksheet_Change and Worksheet_SelectionChange events. Cheers for that suggestion @chris